# How to run latest php code in HHVM 3.30 version?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, devops, hhvm

we are planning to use HHVM service instead of phpfpm7.4 for our application project,
but hhvm version 4 and above doesn't support php anymore, so trying to install hhvm 3.30 version
which support php code , but our project is running on latest laravel php codes , so showing below error,

**Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.2.5". You are running 5.6.99-hhvm**

Is there an option to run latest php codes in hhvm service ??

Tried running HHVM latest version but doesn't support php,

Tried installing hhvm 3.30 version in local but couldn't find the similar version

so, Downloaded docker hhvm 3.30v image directly downloaded from dockerhub but showing below error

**Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.2.5". You are running 5.6.99-hhvm**

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. As you indicate, [HHVM dropped support for the PHP language several years ago](https://hhvm.com/blog/2018/09/12/end-of-php-support-future-of-hack.html). The recommendation from the HHVM team is:

> Ultimately, we recommend that projects either migrate entirely to the Hack language, or entirely to PHP7 and the PHP runtime.

Since you cannot migrate to the Hack language (since none of your dependencies, like Laravel, have done) -- you can't use HHVM and need to use the standard PHP runtime from https://www.php.net -- which was PHP7 at the time and now is PHP8.

Trying to get around this by using an old version of HHVM is also futile. HHVM never properly supported all of the features of PHP7, let alone PHP8. The PHP world has moved on in the intervening 4 years. That's why you're getting the error messages that you are -- things you need depend on PHP7 support, which those ancient versions of HHVM do not provide. (This saying nothing of the security risks of using such an old version of HHVM -- there are multiple known remotely-exploitable security issues in that ancient version, and so using it would be a very bad idea even if you could!)